# C#: Object values null after deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize some XML returned in an API response but all the values in my object are NULL after deserializing.

Below is the XML I am getting in the response that I am trying to deserialize.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ctatt>
    <tmst>20160609 11:50:03</tmst>
    <errCd>0</errCd>
    <errNm />
    <eta>
        <staId>41300</staId>
        <stpId>30252</stpId>
        <staNm>Loyola</staNm>
        <stpDe>Service toward 95th/Dan Ryan</stpDe>
        <rn>803</rn>
        <rt>Red</rt>
        <destSt>30089</destSt>
        <destNm>95th/Dan Ryan</destNm>
        <trDr>5</trDr>
        <prdt>20160609 11:48:45</prdt>
        <arrT>20160609 11:51:45</arrT>
        <isApp>0</isApp>
        <isSch>0</isSch>
        <isDly>0</isDly>
        <isFlt>0</isFlt>
        <flags />
        <lat>42.01906</lat>
        <lon>-87.67289</lon>
        <heading>130</heading>
    </eta>
</ctatt>
```

Here is my class:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("ctatt")]
        public class trainData
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName ="tmst")]
            public string timeStamp { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "errCd")]
            public byte errorCode { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "staId")]
            public ushort stationId { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "stpId")]
            public ushort stopId { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "staNm")]
            public string stationName { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "stpDe")]
            public string stopDesc { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "rn")]
            public ushort runNum { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "rt")]
            public string routeName { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "destSt")]
            public ushort destStation { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "destNm")]
            public string destName { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "trDr")]
            public byte trainDir { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "prdt")]
            public string prdTime {get; set;}

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "arrT")]
            public string arrTime { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "isApp")]
            public ushort isApp { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "isSch")]
            public ushort isSch { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "isDly")]
            public ushort isDly { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "isFlt")]
            public ushort isFlt { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "flags")]
            public string flags { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "lat")]
            public double lat { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "lon")]
            public double lon { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "heading")]
            public ushort heading { get; set; }
        }
```

And here is the code I am using to deserialize:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameters);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(trainData));
                    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
                    {
                        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(reader))
                        {
                            trainData result = (trainData)deserializer.Deserialize(xr);
                            Console.WriteLine("Station Name: {0}\nRoute Name: {1}\nArrival Time: {2}", result.stationName, result.routeName, result.arrTime);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error!");
                }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You should also include the stacktrace you are getting.

Comment: `trainData` needs an `eta` type as a property. Those elements nested within `eta` cannot be deserialized on `trainData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml you provided has 2 layers `ctatt` and `eta`. Yet your model has only a single layer. Of course this is not going to work.

You need to change your model to keep the layout the same with the xml :

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("ctatt")]
public class trainDataResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName ="tmst")]
    public string timeStamp { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errCd")]
    public byte errorCode { get; set; }

    // uncomment next lines to include `errNm`
    //[XmlElement(ElementName = "errNm")]
    //public string errorName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "eta")]
    public TrainData eta { get; set; }
}

public class TrainData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "staId")]
    public ushort stationId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "stpId")]
    public ushort stopId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "staNm")]
    public string stationName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "stpDe")]
    public string stopDesc { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "rn")]
    public ushort runNum { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "rt")]
    public string routeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "destSt")]
    public ushort destStation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "destNm")]
    public string destName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "trDr")]
    public byte trainDir { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "prdt")]
    public string prdTime {get; set;}

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "arrT")]
    public string arrTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isApp")]
    public ushort isApp { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isSch")]
    public ushort isSch { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isDly")]
    public ushort isDly { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "isFlt")]
    public ushort isFlt { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "flags")]
    public string flags { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lat")]
    public double lat { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lon")]
    public double lon { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "heading")]
    public ushort heading { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a property in trainingDataResult for the <errNm> element.  Otherwise, this answer seems correct.

Comment: @RalphAllanRice Indeed, but it was missing as well in OP's source.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  When I update the model per above I am now getting an error saying that "<ctatt xmlns=' '> is not expected.  I ran into this issue earlier and solved it by adding the XmlRoot attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to deserialize a list of elements from a file but maybe it helps...

```
   List<trainData> result = new List<trainData>;
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Filepath,Filemode.Open)
{
XmlSerializer Serializer =new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<trainData>));
result = Serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If  is a complexType, I believe it need as class to represent that entire element. Create a second class (for example "ETAData") to contain the elements under the .  You will also need a property of that type in your trainData class and have it marked with [XmlElementAttribute] also.

EDIT: @Xiaoy312 answer is more concise and basically illustrates what I stated.